# Angularjs Check all in scope of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want all checkboxes checked, inside a loop of a loop. But how?

```
<section ng-repeat="user in users">

    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>

    <label for="#">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkAllRoles(user)"> CHECK ALL
    </label>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="role in user.roles">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ role.id }}"> {{ role.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Add this to the end of your input  closing "checked>"

Comment: Do you know check all checkboxes in the *second* `ng-repeat` when you click the ng-click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to use `ngChange` handler to loop through all roles changing some property like `checked` bound to `ngModel` directive:

```
$scope.checkAllRoles = function(user) {
    user.roles.forEach(function(role) {
        role.checked = user.allChecked;
    });
};
```

Where HTML is this:

```
<section ng-repeat="user in users">

    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>

    <label for="#">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.allChecked" ng-change="checkAllRoles(user)"> CHECK ALL
    </label>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="role in user.roles">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ role.id }}" ng-model="role.checked">{{ role.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>

</section>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/a3I4DKyz6DRUKTIt50Xj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Just add **checked** to the end of your input.

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="role in user.roles">
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{ role.id }}" checked> {{ role.name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nope, check my ng-click on the first checkbox.

Comment: You didn't provide any code for the checkAllRoles(). You said in your question you wanted all checkboxes checked.